# Inserting jQuery's Sortable list into MySql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to insert jquery's sortable list values into MySql. I have issues with looping in MySql while inserting.
I have sorted items like this

```
-------------
 Sorted List
-------------
   did-1
   fid-1
   fid-2
   fid-3
```

After this I have used 'serialize' to get these sorted list

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
connectWith: '.sortable',
tolerance: 'pointer',
update: function (event, ui) {
    $('#add_list').click(function(){        
        var data = $('#drop_list1').sortable('serialize');
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'addnewlist.php',
            success: function(data){                    
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

**What i want is** - Multiple insertion for every 'did', a 'fid' should be inserted. In my MqSql - '(did-1 , fid-1)(did-1 , fid-2)(did-1 , fid-3)'

I have tried this in my PHP.

```
foreach($_POST['doc'] as $doc)
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['doc']);$i++)
    {
        $form=$_POST[$i]['form'];
        echo $sql="INSERT INTO addnewdoc(doc_id,form_id) VALUES ($doc,$form)";
        $res=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the order of the values significant?

Comment: did can have only one. fid can have multiple entries and can have any order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly you want to loop through the docs, and then loop through the forms for each doc.  Will this work instead?

```
foreach($_POST['doc'] as $doc)
{
    foreach($_POST['form'] as $form)
    {
        echo $sql="INSERT INTO addnewdoc(doc_id,form_id) VALUES ($doc,$form)";
        $res=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
    }
}
```

That ends up running an insert query for each combination.  You would be better off building all of the values into a single query and then executing it one time.  For example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO addnewdoc(doc_id,form_id) VALUES ";
$values = Array();
foreach($_POST['doc'] as $doc)
{
    foreach($_POST['form'] as $form)
        $values[] = "($doc,$form)";
}
$sql .= join(',', $values);
$res=parent::_executeQuery($sql);
```

That gathers all of the values into an array and then joins each of them into a string separated by commas.  You can then run a single insert query to insert all of the values.

Comment: for supposse if i have  'did-1 , fid-1' in my sorting list , i am getting multiple entries. i mean multiple insert queries are being executed

Comment: You should print out the $_POST array and make sure you have the array indexes correct.